# Save in scientific notation and save with different sep

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I save the python dataframe in scientific format. Second question is in regard to how to save the data frame in a proper way.  Here is my example:

```
        koefi       300Grad       500Grad        620Grad
0         nu  3.300000e-01  3.300000e-01       0.330000
1         bk  1.021627e+02  7.491372e+02     200.000000
2   alphaChi  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00       1.000000
3    betaChi  2.500000e-01  2.500000e-01       0.250000
4         sn  1.535676e+00  5.246025e+00       3.500000
5         sk  2.070121e+02  1.000000e+02     116.152032
```

Currently I can only save it with `sep = '\t'` but not not `sep = '\s+'` or something different. As with the scientific format so far I only found: `float_format='%.6f`.

My current output:

```
    koefi   300Grad 500Grad 620Grad
0   nu  0.330000    0.330000    0.330000
1   bk  102.162699  749.137166  200.000000
2   alphaChi    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000
3   betaChi 0.250000    0.250000    0.250000
4   sn  1.535676    5.246025    3.500000
5   sk  207.012055  100.000000  116.15203
```

It looks not particularly nice, someone here has any idea to save it in a better way, so it looks more pleasant.

```
list_final.to_csv(path_or_buf='Z:/simul/results/result.dat', index=True, sep='\s+', decimal='.',float_format='%.6f')
```

> TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: I tried to install prettytable in Anaconda Prompt with install -c synthicity prettytable.

And got the Error:

> UnstatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in
>   conflict: - anaconda == 5.2.0 =py36_3 -> sqlite[version
>   ='3.23.1,>=3.23.1, <4.0a0', build= h35aae40_0] 
>   - prettytable

Comment: Please format your data properly by using code blocks. Also, do not use profanity on this website. It's a small thing, but it makes the site much more relaxed to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just save the file as a CSV?  It's a standardized format that anyone can understand, and there exists tons of software to visualize CSV files in a prettier way.

If you really need to view the raw text file and if you want it to be pretty, then you could try the [PrettyTable](http://zetcode.com/python/prettytable/) library.  It won't work out-of-the-box with pandas `to_csv`, so you'll have to do a little more work.

To format the numbers in scientific notation, you can pass `float_format='%.2E'`.

**Edit:**

Here's an example of how you might beautify your output with PrettyTable:

```py
# in your virtual environment: pip install PTable
from prettytable import PrettyTable

my_table = PrettyTable()
my_table.field_names = ['index', *list_final.columns]

for idx, row in list_final.iterrows():
    formatted_row = [idx]
    for val in row.values:
        if isinstance(val, str):
            formatted_row.append(val)
        else:
            formatted_row.append('%.2E' % val)

    my_table.add_row(formatted_row)

with open('Z:/simul/results/result.dat', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(str(my_table))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. Firstly your solution for the scientific notation seems to be working. But to save it as .csv does not give a satisfying solution. Secondly, I still have the Problem the separator.

Comment: I edited my answer to show how you can use the PrettyTable library to make your text file nicer.  I think this should also ease your concerns about the separator, since PrettyTable will automatically insert nice-looking separators and center the columns

Comment: I Edit my question to show that I could not install prettytable at least in anaconda.

Comment: It looks like the `prettytable` package on the anaconda cloud is pretty out-of-date.  It wants to use Python 2.  You can install pip packages in conda environments.  Activate your environment, and try `pip install PTable`.

Comment: Thank you very much this seems to do the trick. And I have to say the results look pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame.to_csv(...)` is for storing data in csv/dsv format not for nice look. Consider the following approach to save your data like a kinda nice table:

```
import pandas as pd

# sample data
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {'300grad': [.33, .0162],
     '500grad': [.33, 245],
     '620grad': [.33, 395_000]},
    index=['nu', 'mumumu'])

# format templates
bones_head = '{:>8}' + '{:>10}' * data.shape[1] + '\n'
bones_line = '{:>8}' + '{:>10.2e}' * data.shape[1] + '\n'

# save data to file according to format templates
with open('2.csv', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(bones_head.format('', *data.columns))
    for dummy, row in data.iterrows():
        fout.write(bones_line.format(row.name, *row))
```

Result:

```
           300grad   500grad   620grad
      nu  3.30e-01  3.30e-01  3.30e-01
  mumumu  1.62e-02  2.45e+02  3.95e+05
```

Another way - with modifying index and columns:

```
import pandas as pd

# sample data
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {'300grad': [.33, .0162],
     '500grad': [.33, 245],
     '620grad': [.33, 395_000]},
    index=['nu', 'mumumu'])

# modify index values to have the same width
index_width = max(len(val) for val in data.index)
data.index = [' ' * (index_width - len(val)) + val for val in data.index]
data.index.name = ' ' * index_width

# modify column names to have the same width
col_width = max(10, *(len(val) for val in data.columns))
data.columns = [' ' * (col_width - len(val)) + val for val in data.columns]

# save data to file
data.to_csv('1.csv', float_format=f'%{col_width}.2e')
```

Result:

```
      ,   300grad,   500grad,   620grad
    nu,  3.30e-01,  3.30e-01,  3.30e-01
mumumu,  1.62e-02,  2.45e+02,  3.95e+05
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice solution, the only Probleme at least with var 1 seems to be with {:>10.2e} and here with e ValueError: Unknown format code 'e' for object of type 'str'. Only when I erase the e it worked properly